# how to pass id on cell selection for update value to edit class in sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want pass particular ID on cell .If user need to change there profile then he/she click on edit button after click edit button the tableview is gone on edit mode after this if user click any cell then edit page is call for update value .so here how to pass ID on cell selection .so user can change there value from edit class for partiular row

I create one modle class with -(void)update method i give all sqlite object for change but how to pass Id for update method for change on cell selection please help me

how to pass here id for update for paticular cell value should change mu p**rimary id is TaskID**

this is my code for edit class

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [MyTableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (self.editing) {
        EditTask* content = [[EditTask alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditTask" bundle:nil];
        content.navigationItem.title = @"Edit Task";
        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: content]; 
        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                    initWithContentViewController:navController];
         [content release];
        [navController release];

        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                    initWithContentViewController:navController];
        _popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(350, 450);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell.contentView 
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Like this.
in did select event

```
NSString *strid =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
```

so strid is your id.

Comment: it's NSString *strid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];